# Cant inherit from ViewModelProvider.Factory in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-viewmodel

I am trying to create a ViewModel for an android appliction I am developing using kotlin and I want to inherit from ViewModelProvider.Factory in kotlin but I am getting the error
*"Inheritance from an interface with '@JvmDefault' members is only allowed with -Xjvm-default option"*
When I try inheriting the ViewModelProvider.Factory class.
Below is my code

```
package com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp.bamidelenewsapp.ui.viewmodel

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp.bamidelenewsapp.repository.NewsRepository

class NewsViewModelProviderFactory(val newsRepository: NewsRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return NewsViewModel(newsRepository) as T
    }
}
```

Any advice on how to fix this would be highly appreciated

Comment: have you find the answer of this issue? I need this answer too